# When I start my Compose application the colors are tale and it does not look right

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

When I build my Jetpack Compose application for my Desktop it is tale and looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I expected it to look like the example Application from the wizard.

Code (Exactly like on [The Wizzard](https://kmp.jetbrains.com/?_gl=1*1ifv3tz*_ga*MjA2Mjk4ODA4LjE3MTExODgxMzc.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTcxMTIyODI4Mi44LjEuMTcxMTIyODQ0MC40NC4wLjA.&_ga=2.180192355.690894644.1711188139-206298808.1711188137)):

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.ExperimentalResourceApi
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.painterResource
import org.jetbrains.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

import yousic.composeapp.generated.resources.Res
import yousic.composeapp.generated.resources.compose_multiplatform

@OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        var showContent by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Button(onClick = { showContent = !showContent }) {
                Text("Click me!")
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(showContent) {
                val greeting = remember { Greeting().greet() }
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Image(painterResource(Res.drawable.compose_multiplatform), null)
                    Text("Compose: $greeting")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We have to take a look at your code. Can you please edit your question and add the relevant code parts to it?

Comment: I added the code I hope it helps to solve my problem!

Comment: Do the colors look right on a mobile device?

Comment: I do not included Mobile I just want to build a Desktop only Application